# Add keys to values already inside a key and then add extra value and key based on key name

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a nested dict from a dict I have already created. In my dict for every key I have a list of values. I want to add an additional key to those values and then create a new key and value pair, the value being from the original key for all those values previously. I am also generating the dictionary from two other dictionaries if that is relevant (Sorry it's hard for me to explain)

**Code used to make original dict**

```
dict1 = cls.make_ssc() 
dict2 = cls.make_tg()
dictfinal = {}
for key in dict1.keys():
      dictfinal[key] = [dict1[key], dict2[key]]
      return dictfinal
```

This is kind of what I have now:

**{'blue': ['dog', 'carrot'], 'red': ['cat', 'peas'], 'yellow': ['elephant', 'broccoli'],}**

I would like to make this:

**{'blue': {'color': 'blue', 'animal': 'dog', 'vegetable': 'carrot'}, 'red': {'color': 'red', 'animal': 'cat', 'vegetable': 'peas'}, 'yellow': {'color': 'yellow', 'animal': 'elephant', 'vegetable': 'broccoli'},}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need `dict` with `zip`

**Ex:**

```
dictfinal = {}
keys = ['color', 'animal', 'vegetable']
for key in dict1.keys():
      dictfinal[key] = dict(zip(keys, [key, dict1[key], dict2[key]]))
return dictfinal
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!